# How to remember SVN credentials in Sublime Text

Tags: eclipse, svn, ssh, sublimetext3, code-editor

OS: Ubuntu 12.04,
Sublime version : Sublime Text 3,
Package for SVN: Wbond SVN for sublime Text,
Problem: I am using sublime text 3 as code editor and SVN as version control. Everything is working fine like, update, commit, difference etc. I just face one issue every time I go for commit or update, Sublime text asks for my SVN credentials again and again. I want to save these credentials once and do not want to enter again and again like it happens in Eclipse.

can somebody please help me in knowing how to do so?

Comment: I don't use the plugin but the docs seem to indicate that it just uses the command line SVN client, so you might want to try using that to set the credentials first and see if the plugin stops asking you.

Comment: @OdatNurd: I have tried checking out and updating code using command line in Ubuntu. I have entered credentials there. But, when I use Sublime Text, credentials are asked every time. Is there anything else I should try?

Comment: `~/.subversion/config` is the subversion config file. Make sure that `store-passwords` is not set to `no` in there. That controls whether or not subversion saves auth information.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing svn over ssh and setting a default ssh key for that host, then using the friendly-name for the connection. If your server allows for ssh, I'll be glad to expand on this.